# How to optimize use of querysets with lists

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model that has a couple million objects. Each object represents a call made/received by a company.

To simplify things, let's say this model, Call, has these fields:
calldate, context, channel.

My goal is to know the average # of calls made and received during each hour of the day of the month (load by hour). The catch is: I need to find this for **port1** and **port2** separately.

As of now, my code works fine, except that it takes around 1 whole minute to give me the result for a range of 4 months and I it seems extremely inefficient.

I've done some simple profiling and discovered that the **extend** is taking around 99% of the processing time:

```
queryset = Call.objects.filter(calldate__gte='SOME_DATE')
port1, port2 = [],[]
port1.extend(queryset.filter(context__icontains="e1-1"))
port2.extend(queryset.filter(context__icontains="e1-2"))
channels_in_port1 = ["Port/%d-2" % x for x in range(1,32)]
channels_in_port2 = ["Port/%d-2" % x for x in range(32,63)]

for i in channels_in_port1:
    port1.extend(queryset.filter(channel__icontains=i))
for i in channels_in_port2:
    port2.extend(queryset.filter(channel__icontains=i))
```

port1 and port2 have around 150k objects combined now.

As soon as I have all calls for **port1** and **port2**, I'm good to go. The rest of the code is basically some for loops for **port1** and **port2** that sums up and takes the average of calls according to the hour/day/month. Trivial stuff.

I tried to avoid using any "extend" by using itertools.chain and chaining the querysets instead. However, that made the processing time shift to the part where I do the trivial for loops to calculate the load by hour.

Any alternatives? Better ways to filter the queryset?
Thanks very much!!

Comment: Can you post the code for your model?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using django's aggregate functions?  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

I presume your problem is with the second set of extends, ie those within the for loops, rather than the first. (The first is completely unnecessary, in any case: rather than defining an empty list up front and extending it, you can just do `port1 = list(queryset.filter(context__icontains="e1-1"))`.)

Anyway, to summarize what I think you are trying to do: you want to get all `Call` objects for a certain date, in two blocks depending on the value for `channel`: one where it contains values from 0 to 31, and one with values between 32 and 62.

It seems like you could do this with just two queries, without any extending at all:

```
port1 = queryset.filter(channel__range=["Port/1-2", "Port/31-2"])
port2 = queryset.filter(channel__range=["Port/1-32", "Port/31-62"])
```

Does that not do what you want?

**Edit in response to comment** but that's then just two queries which you *can* extend, or concatenate. The problem with your code as posted is that you are doing *31* queries and extend operations for each port, which is bound to be expensive. If you just do one each, plus one extend/concat, that will be much cheaper.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that the first part is unnecessary, but casting the queryset into a list takes just about the same processing time as extending it. Either case, it doesn't matter here really. :) 
The second part, making two queries like you mentioned wouldn't work and here's why: port1 should be a list that contains both Call objects with the defined channel range AND Call objects where the field "context" is "e1-1". These two aren't found together. I can't just chain filters. I might have to look into aggregate functions like Aaron mentioned, or maybe, just breaking it into more lists...